# Select Json object keys as columns in prestodb (sql)

Tags: sql, presto

This is my database:

mytable

---

| SensorID | Name | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prox | {"O3":33, "CO2":12, "PM10":12"} |
| 3 | IR | {"O3":33, "CO2":12, "PM10":12"} |

---

`SELECT  (how to select field without mentioning object keys?)  FROM mytable WHERE SensorID=1`

actually, I tried this method it's working :

**`SELECT SensorID, Name, Data.O3, Data.CO2, Data.PM10 FROM mytable WHERE SensorID=1`**

The problem is sometimes I don't know what are values inside the object of the Data column

Excepted output is:

| SensorID | Name | O3 | CO2 | PM10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prox | 33 | 12 | 12 |

How can I achieve this...

Comment: You can't.  If you don't know what's in the JSON, then you will have to parse the JSON in your programming language.  This is one reason why I have an issue with storing JSON in a relational table.

Comment: `Data.O3, Data.CO2, Data.PM10` - looks like you have a table containing `ROW`, not json

Comment: What is the return of `select typeof(Data) from mytable`?